# How to find variable declarator for an identifier using Babel?

Tags: babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Suppose I have the following piece of code and wish to find the variable declaration for the `needle` identifier in the `foo(needle)` call expression:

```
import { foo } from 'bar'

const needle = 'bad'

function deep () {
  let needle = 0
  needle = 1

  function deeper () {
    foo(needle)
  }
}
```

What would I need to use with Babel to write something robust that could try to resolve the last value assigned to `needle`, if a variable declaration for it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.scope.getBinding('needle')`

`path.scope.getAllBindings()` for all.